# HCE payment application workflow

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I am doing a PoC on HCE based payment.I have gone through Android documentation and some other blogs and it seems its pretty complex to implement.

There is a sample app describing the HCE service for core communication but I beleive a real payment app has much more. e.g. I see following modules

1) user enrollment/registraion - user will get a PIN after successful registration. This PIN will be required while making payment
2) card registration - once registered cards will be stored on cloud.
3) HCE module to communicate with NFC reader at POS (point of sale)
4) token generation to perform transactions - It is one of mechanisms to prevent/minimise fraud as a token may have a lifetime, amount or no. of transactions limitation. I have not understood it fully as how the token will be generated and who all are involved in the process.

please help me to clarify this workflow.

Thanks,
iuq

Comment: Kindly give a reason or suggest a change/correction before giving -1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the flow I was looking for, found it [here](http://www.cartaworldwide.com/technology/host-card-emulation/)

**1. Registration:**
The end-user registers with their Issuing Bank for the mobile payments service, electing a card to mobilize for proximity payments, and installs the handset application
**2. Card Preparation:**
The Issuing Bank shares details of the elected payment card with the Remote Secure Element in readiness for tokenization
**3. Handset Preparation:**
The end-user activates and initializes their handset and mobile application with the Remote Secure Element

**4. Payment Token Provisioning:**
The Remote Secure Element provisions payment tokens to the handset mobile application ready for use in proximity payments

**5. Proximity Payments:**
The end-user activates a payment token within the handset mobile application and presents their handset to a POS terminal to make a payments